# Dotnet EF Core 2.1 throws QueryClientEvaluationWarning when querying decimal property

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, ef-core-2.1

I have a C# class Loan that is mapped to a Loans table in a SQL Server database. I am using DotNet EF Core 2.1. to interact with the database from my code.

```
    public class Loan
    {
       public decimal Rate { get;set; }
       // Other properties omitted for brevity
    }
```

When I create my database connection I am configuring it to throw exceptions when a query cannot be executed server side as follows:

```
    services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
            options
                .UseSqlServer(systemConfiguration.DatabaseConnectionString)
                .ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Throw(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning)));
```

The problem is that when querying the decimal column using LINQ:

```
    // Obtain DbContext from services
    var loans = await dbContext.Loans.Where(l => l.Rate > 1.5m).ToListAsync();
```

An exception is thrown as the query cannot be executed server side. Other numeric property types such as int work fine.

Comment: How is the column defined in the database table?

Comment: @MarkWagoner decimal(18,4) not null

Comment: Seems to work with the same DB column but a double C# property.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help you but if you're using EF code first you can specify the scale and precision in the configuration class.  For example:

```
modelBuilder.Property(x => x.PurchaseCost).HasColumnType("decimal(12,6)");
```

My PurchaseCost property of the class is defined as type decimal.

Comment: I've already defined the column type as decimal (18,4) by using a ColumnAttribute on the property declaration but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is not actually an issue when running against SQL Server. The issue was in my integration tests which were using SQLite